# Clickonce - UnInstall running application

Tags: clickonce, uninstallation

I have made clickonce installer for my application. The issue is when if my application is running and I remove that application from Add/Remove programs, it removes the entry from Installed Applications(shown in add/remove programs window), but my application is not un-installed.

I read through some links and found that if application is running then clickonce marks it as un-installed and files are removed as soon as application is closed. But it doesnt happen in my case :(

Can anyone tell me, how can I handle this ?

After reading the comment, i tried to reboot my machine and below is my observation...
I cheked my application uninstallation after marking it not to auto start at machine reboot, and un-install works perfectly, I guess since my application start automatically at machine restart, machine is never able to do clean up work. any solution to handle this situation??

Comment: After clickonce has marked the running software as needing to be removed, try rebooting the machine. Uninstallers sometimes place some kind of instruction/marker to do extra work at the next boot.

Comment: I have tried re-booting the machine. The thing is my application starts automatically when machine restart, So I guess machine is not able to do extra work as after machine is restarted, my application is running, which was expected to be not running..can that be a factor ???

Comment: I cheked my application uninstallation after marking it not to auto start at machine reboot, and un-install works perfectly, I guess since my application start automatically at machine restart, machine is never able to do clean up work. any solution to handle this situation??